# How i can iterate throught objects and array

Tags: javascript

I have this example, but i dont know how to start for get the values of objects

```
const initialState = {
    orders:[{
        0:{
            0: {hex: "#8A2BE2", name: "blueviolet", price: "1", quantity: 1},
            1: {hex: "#FFE4C4", name: "bisque", price: "1.4", quantity: 1}
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Also `initialState.orders[0][0][0]` is the first and `initialState.orders[0][0][1]` is the second. The real question is why is the data arranged this way, it's very hard to work with

Comment: What exactly are you trying to iterate? You have an object with an array of objects with numbers for keys that also has numbers for keys. The answer depends on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have two Objects in `order` property of `initialState`.
First you have this:

```js
initialState.order
```

then because it's an array you have to do this

```js
initialState.order[0]
```

and then you have two property named "0"

```js
initialState.orders[0]["0"]["0"]
```

now you can have your entire data like this

```js
initialState.orders[0]["0"]["0"].hex
```

```js
const initialState = {
    orders:[{
        0:{
            0: {hex: "#8A2BE2", name: "blueviolet", price: "1", quantity: 1},
            1: {hex: "#FFE4C4", name: "bisque", price: "1.4", quantity: 1}
        }
    }]
}
console.log(initialState.orders[0]["0"]["0"].hex);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you would have to call on the variable `initialState`
which is an object with a value of `orders` set to an array
which contains 1 object
Which contains 2 values
Each of those values containing an object of 4 values

```
initialState.orders[0][0][0]
// {hex: "#8A2BE2", name: "blueviolet", price: "1", quantity: 1}

initialState.orders[0][0][1]
// {hex: "#FFE4C4", name: "bisque", price: "1.4", quantity: 1}

initialState.orders[0][0][1].name
// "bisque"
```

You can go farther with it all the way down to one of the last values if you wanted.